# The screen.debug() markup differs from the snapshort markup in React testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

After clicking the sectionDeleteButton the confirmationModal appears. It is seen in the **browser console**. It is seen in **screen.debug()**. But why it is not rendered in **snapshot**?

```
const { asFragment } = renderWithProviders(<CasingColumnsTable />, { preloadedState })

    await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('casing-columns-table'), { timeout: 1000 })
    const expandRowButton = screen.getByTestId(
      'down-outlined-icon-id-da96e7dd-fa49-4915-87ae-ab6680f303e4',
    )
    fireEvent.click(expandRowButton)
    const sectionDeleteButton = screen.getByTestId('sectionDeleteButton')
    fireEvent.click(sectionDeleteButton)
    await screen.findByTestId('confirmationModal')
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
    screen.debug(undefined, 100000)
```

Comment: What did you see in the browser console? And what did you see in `screen.debug()`? Show more details.